# el navbar tapa el titulo cuando hago mi enlance interno

Tags: html, css3, responsive, bootstrap

Bueno tengo un par de problemas con mi navbar de boostrap. Entrando en contexto:

cada uno de los items del navbar tiene enlaces directos dentro de la misma pagina `<a href="#">` cuando le doy click a alguno de ellos efectivamente me lleva a cada uno de los elementos pero el mismo navbar me tapa el titulo. Ahora no quiero ni ocultar el navbar ya que dinamicamente el se muestra o no, y cambiando el padding o el margin del titulo tampoco funciona aqui les dejo 2 imagenes, la 1ra. de como lo muestra al darle click y la otra como me gustaria que lo mostrara

Asi es como se muestra
[image: ..]
Asi es como quiero que se vea

[image: ...]

---

```
     <div id = miDIV>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="download_CV">
          <a href="./assets/cv/CV Jose Valero  - English V.pdf" target="_blank">
            <p>Curriculum <i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt"></i></p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div  id="mainListDiv" class="main_list">
          <ul class="navlinks">
            <li><a id="asd" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/josemiguelvalero/" target="_blank"><i
                  class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/jose-valero" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="tuID" href="#about">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a id="tuID" href="#experience">Experience </a></li>
            <li><a id="tuID" href="#education">Education</a></li>
            <li><a id="tuID" href="#courses">Courses</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <span class="navTrigger">
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>


 <script> 
        $("#tuID").click(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop($('#miDIV').offset().top - 100);})
      </script>
```

asi lo coloque

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Sin tener el **HTML** y el **CSS** necesarios para poder reproducir tu problema es difícil encontrar la causa. Las imágenes son un buen aporte a modo de apoyo, pero estas nunca deben de sustituir al código.

Answer (score 1):

Se que tiene tiempo el post mi estimado , logre hacer funcionar el menú pegajoso o sticky solo con CSS , esto va como posible solución a los futuros desarrolladores que tuvieron el mismo problema que nosotros .
Agregue lo siguiente a su hoja CSS.

```css
[id] {
   scroll-margin-top: 3.8em;
}
```

Donde el valor 3.8 em -> corresponde al tamaño que se salta antes del titulo , cambiar según les parezca mas atractivo , Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar las funciones de jquery offset() y scrolltop().

Agregale un id a tu div y en en el evento click, redireccionalo a ese div y podes sumarle o restarle los pixeles que quieras. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
$("#miBoton").click(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($('#miDIV').offset().top - 100);
};
```

Saludos!

Comment: Saludos Nicolas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme, pero le puse el ID como me recomendaste al DIV que esta de primero e hice algo asi:

$("#education").click(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($('#miDIV').offset().top - 100);
});

y no logre ningún resultado, tengo cortos 5 meses aprendiendo y bueno si me puedes explicar para sigue sin funcionar seria de mucha ayuda. 

Gracias

Comment: De nada, te hago dos preguntas: Tenes incluidas las librerias jquery verdad? por otra parte veo que le asignaste el id "education" a tu botón, también le agregaste el id "miDIV" al div al que queres scrollear verdad?

Comment: si tengo las las lirerias de jquery

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pude lograr que se moviera a donde queria intercambiando el `href` por un `id` ahora, en el caso del primer item se mueve perfecto pero en los otros items no hace nada. para aclarar ya verifique en todas secciones del html que esten bien escritos y en el lugar correcto todos mis ID, y revise la funcion tambien en el archivo .js 
ahora para cada uno de los items del navbar hice algo asi:

```
$("#aboutButton").click(function () {
    $(window).scrollTop($('#about').offset().top - 180);
});

$("#experienceButton").click(function () {
    $(window).scrollTop($('#experience').offset().top - 350);
 });

$("#educationButton").click(function () {
    $(window).scrollTop($('#education').offset().top - 500);
  });
```

ahora solo se mueve cuando le doy en about y en los otros items no hace nada. tengo ya un par de dias quizas con este problema tonto pero nada que consigo solución, sera ceguera de codigo idk